# Handshake error in PHP call to SurveyMonkey API V3

Tags: php, api, handshake, surveymonkey

I am new to REST and have been tasked with retrieving SurveyMonkey survey data using the V3 API.  I am using PHP.  My code is as follows:

```
$fields = array(
'title'=>'New Admission Survey',
'object_ids' => array($surveyID));

$fieldsString = json_encode($fields);

$curl = curl_init();
$requestHeaders = array(
"Authorization" => 'bearer abc123',
"Content-Type" => 'application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fieldsString));

$baseUrl = 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3';
$endpoint = '/surveys/';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl . $endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

if($curl_response == false){
echo('Well, crap');
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo('<pre>');print_r($info);echo('</pre>');
echo('<pre>');print_r(curl_error($curl));echo('</pre>');}
else {
echo('Test: ' . $curl_response);}

curl_close($curl);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have verified the Auth Token I am using is the one issued to me when I registered my app (done today).

Am I missing something?  Most of the questions and answers deal with V2 of the SurveyMonkey API.  I am using V3.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Issue looks like it's not with your token or anything, seems like a TLS error, make sure your server has the supported ciphers. You can see what SurveyMonkey supports here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.surveymonkey.net&latest . For *testing* you can probably disable handshake verification if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks!  I believe you are correct.  When it is working, I will post the solution and credit you...

Comment: No joy.  I am using OpenSSL v 0.9.8c and TLS1.0.  Is an upgrade needed?

Comment: To be clear, I edited my code to set the following: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  -- still getting the same error

Comment: I'm not sure the specifics, but I think you need TLS1.2 now, or at least use a supported cipher specified in the link above. According to the link I sent you, only cipher supported for TLS 1.0/1.1 is `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` but I'm not an expert on SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help the specific error you're encountering, but have you tried using this API wrapper? https://github.com/ghassani/surveymonkey-v3-api-php

This API wrapper simplified my tasks considerably:

```
<?php

// Init the client.
$client = Spliced\SurveyMonkey\Client(MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);

// Get a specific survey.
$survey = $client->getSurvey(MY_SURVEY_ID);

// Get all responses for this survey.
/** @var Spliced\SurveyMonkey\Response $responses */
$responses = $client->getSurveyResponses(MY_SURVEY_ID);

// Get a specific response.
/** @var Spliced\SurveyMonkey\Response $response */
$response = $client->getSurveyResponse(MY_SURVEY_ID, RESPONSE_ID, TRUE);

/* etc... */
```